# `find` finds nfs server?

Tags: macos, bash, nfs

I had to run `find / -name foo > found.txt` and stumbled over the following output:

```
...
find: /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/mac/2014-12-17-162004/MacRoot/.DocumentRevisions-V100: Permission denied
nfs server localhost:/FjbUHyS_WAWZQyX9SZ1Wx9: not responding
nfs server localhost:/FjbUHyS_WAWZQyX9SZ1Wx9: is alive again
nfs server localhost:/FjbUHyS_WAWZQyX9SZ1Wx9: not responding
nfs server localhost:/FjbUHyS_WAWZQyX9SZ1Wx9: is alive again
nfs server localhost:/FjbUHyS_WAWZQyX9SZ1Wx9: not responding
nfs server localhost:/FjbUHyS_WAWZQyX9SZ1Wx9: is alive again
nfs server localhost:/FjbUHyS_WAWZQyX9SZ1Wx9: not responding
nfs server localhost:/FjbUHyS_WAWZQyX9SZ1Wx9: is alive again
find: /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/mac/2014-12-17-162004/MacRoot/System/Library/DirectoryServices/DefaultLocalDB/Default: Permission denied
...
```

I'm not using NFS nor have I ever mounted a NFS volume. Where is this coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS is runnning Time Machine backups for you, even if your Time Machine disk is not connected. The backup directory is automatically created and mounted as a network share via NFS at the /Volumes/Mobilebackups directory. 
This is not a backup in the disaster recovery sense, but it will allow you to restore older versions of your files, if you by accident delete a file or regret an edit you did.
Supposedly it will consume a lot of disk space, but only as long as there's at least 20 % free space.

Disable the service with this terminal command if you dont like it:

```
sudo tmutil disablelocal
```

To see the NFS path, run the mount command. Optionally "mount -a" to show all volumes.

I believe the physical location of the backups is i /.Mobilebackups but I'm not quite sure.

And according to Apple docs, the find command should take an option "-fstype" with the special value "local" to stay within the same file system, thus avoiding mounted network shares etc. (Not tested - have no access to a Mac system right now).

```
find / -fstype local -name foo
```

*)https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html

Comment: but how do I see the link/share? `ls -l /Volumes/` shows it as a normal folder: `drwxrwxrwx  0 root  wheel  0 Dec 17 20:55 MobileBackups`